# How can I add a white space around the background color of a table cell in CSS

Tags: html, css, padding

How can I add a white space around the background color of a table cell in CSS?  I have this, but the background color goes all the way to the edge.  Padding seems to work for the content, but not the background color.

```
#main-monitor {
    width: 100%;
}

#main-monitor td, #main-monitor th {
    border: 3px solid #999;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

EDIT: Here's my full CSS that matters to these pieces.  I've made a couple updates, but am still having the same issue.

```
#main-monitor {
    width: 100%;
}

#main-monitor th {
    border: 3px solid #999;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;  
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#main-monitor td {
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    margin: 2px;

}
#main-monitor td span {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

It's being applied to a table in this partial view:

```
<table id="main-monitor">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.A)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.B)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.C)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                        <td style="background-color:@item.AColor"><span>@item.A</span></td>
                        <td style="background-color:@item.BColor"><span>@item.B</span></td>
                        <td style="background-color:@item.CColor">@item.C</td>
                   </tr>
                }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried using border-spacing on the <table>?

Comment: Yeah, tried that but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

As mentioned by  "Advait S", You can use the `border-spacing` css rule for `table` tags

Here is a practical example

```css
td {
  background: red;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Solution 2**

Despite solution 1 is elegant. you can change the display property to your table cell to `inline-block` and then apply a margin to your cells

snippet below

```css
td{ 
background:red;
margin:10px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    <td><span>xxx</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Border-spacing doesn't do anything in my code.  And the inline-block option, though it does work, won't be appropriate for this application.  It's part of a table and has to present the cells with a uniform width.

Comment: "How can I add a white space around the background color of a table cell in CSS"

Comment: Updated the title per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also try this.

1. Write the text of table in span and apply style as.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Hello</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td{
  border: 1px Solid Black;
  background-color: white;
}
td span{
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

See [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpxPGg)

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything for me.